# Can i use DataTable.Select() method to make simple paging?

Tags: c#, performance, select, datatable, paging

I quickly view this MSDN article [using datacolumn.expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx), but have found nothing. It looks like 'select expression' syntax doesn't support paging...

Comment: What article are you refering to?

Comment: * fixed article link.

Comment: I have just changed to the english version for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paging is a mechanism of how you `SELECT` the data. Consider the following test data:

```
ID         Name                 Date
1          Bob                  1/1/2013
2          Bill                 1/3/2013
3          Andy                 2/1/2013
...
```

if I wanted to page that data, and I didn't care how it was sorted, I could do it by `ID` so I could do something like this:

```
var rows = table.Select().Take(10);
_id = (int)rows.Last()["ID"];
```

and that would give me the first ten rows (**i.e.** a page). Note I'm also storing the last `ID` into an assumed class variable named `_id`. How you store, or just recover later, that `ID` depends solely on your program. Now, if I need the next page, I could do something like this:

```
var rows = table.Select("ID > " + _id).Take(10);
_id = (int)rows.Last()["ID"];
```

and that would give me the next page. But what if I wanted to sort that data by `Name`? That changes the game a little. Consider the following code:

```
var rows = table.Select("", "Name").Take(10);
_name = rows.Last()["Name"] as string;
```

that will give me the first page of data, sorted by `Name`. But notice I'm storing the value of `Name` in the assumed class variable `_name` for later. Now when I want the next page I need to do something like this:

```
var rows = table.Select("Name > '" + _name + "'", "Name").Take(10);
_name = rows.Last()["Name"] as string;
```

that will get me the next page, but still ordered by `Name`. **Sorting is very important when it comes to paging.**

***NOTE:*** the code isn't quite as simple as I've put forward. You can't just `Take(10)` because there may not be `10` to take. Further, you may not be able to just **store** the last `ID` or `Name`, you may have to recover it from somewhere every time. Finally, you may need to support multi-sort, where it's sorted by more than one column, so keep that in mind too when providing the sort.

***FINAL NOTE:*** it is much better to leverage **raw SQL** for paging than the aforementioned code - I only provided that code because you asked about the `Select` method on the `DataTable`. It would be much better to simply construct the correct SQL statement, send it to the server, and then just display the results.

Comment: Mmm, i have well written stored procedure, that gets me data from db, and can't rewrite or change it now... So may be the best way for me to use Skip / Take. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Simple paging can be created most simply using LINQ.

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(100).Take(25);
```

Comment: Thank you. But will it be more efficient [use almost 'raw' SQL], than convert it to LINQ?

Comment: Why would you skip 100 out of curiosity?

Comment: @LukeHennerley Pages of 25 rows. To get the 5th page : skip 4 pages (4 * 25) then read page (take 25 items).

Comment: LINQ is fast, I don't think you would see any performance issues.  If you did see performance concerns, you could use LINQ2SQL which woulc do the "top" clause for you.  Guillaume is correct, the example would be the 5th page of 25.

Comment: You are paginating the datatable directly. What if the data set is very large? Server-side, in-memory pagination does nothing for you in that case. You need to pull the data from the source in smaller chunks. Datatable is of little use for this scenario without lazy loading capability.

Comment: @xeon, please read the existing comment thread.  This concern has already been addressed.  This post is also almost 4 years old.  No guarantees this is the best way any longer.

Comment: @xeon I prefer this method of getting paginated data, however, I was wondering how if i made some sort of Paginator class that kept track of current page and page size, how could i retrieve information to determine values such as Next page number/last page number etc?  Short of making an initial call to the db that does a count of rows (without pagination), that's the only way I can see myself getting that information.