# c# data table batch processing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

i have data table with 20,000 rows whats the best way to process by 5000 rows for each time ? 
i want to care about performance also

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable().Skip(x).Take(y)
```

is this way is OK ?

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework?

Comment: Refer this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477296/can-i-use-datatable-select-method-to-make-simple-paging

Answer (score -1):

That should work just fine.  Linq's Skip Method should run very fast.  I suppose it would arguably depend on how much content you DataRows have, but with 3 columns I got nearly instantaneous calls:

```
        DataTable table = TwentyKRows();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            DateTime before = DateTime.Now;
            var test = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(5000 * i).Take(5000);
            DateTime after = DateTime.Now;

            TimeSpan ts = after - before;
            Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString());
        }
```

Output:

```
00:00:00.0099991
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```